# Como puedo desactivar un checkbox una vez seleccionado

Tags: php, javascript, html

Intentaré explicarlo de la manera más clara; Necesito que al activar mi checkbox este se desactive o se ponga en solo lectura y también guardar ese proceso, para que el refrescar o cerrar la página no tenga que volver a activarlo, hasta el momento guardo la selección del checkbox con localStorage, el detalle que puedo volver a deseleccionar el checkbox y ya no sirve de nada el código, en mi caso no es problema ya que se que no debo picarle de nuevo, tengo otro código para desactivarlo una vez haga la selección, el detalle que si le pico de nuevo, mando una alerta y aunque le diga que no mi otro código toma ese clic como una deseleccion y ya no guarda la selección qué hice, abajo dejo el código para guardar la selección y el otro que bloquea el checkbox.

```
<script>
(function() {

  var cbstate;
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
 
    cbstate = JSON.parse(localStorage['CBState'] || '{}');
  
    for(var i in cbstate) {
      var el = document.querySelector('input[name="' + i + '"]');
      if (el) el.checked = true;
    }
  
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('save-cb-state');
  
    for(var i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
       cb[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    
        if (this.checked) {
          cbstate[this.name] = true;
        }
    
        else if (cbstate[this.name]) {
          delete cbstate[this.name];
        }
    
        localStorage.CBState = JSON.stringify(cbstate);
      });
    }
  });
})();
</script>

<script>
$("#test").on('change', function() {
    this.checked=!this.checked?!confirm():true;
});</script>
```

Comment: Publicá el código HTML. Sería ideal que tu ejemplo se pudiera probar desde acá. Probá editar tu pregunta y agregar el código como un _fragmento_.

Comment: listo, hasta abajo está y ahí hay otro detalle, pero primero lo primero @azeós

Answer (score 0):

Lo que entiendo que estas pidiendo es una funcion de una unica accion, para ello no te recomiendo que lo hagas desde el localstorage ya que es memoria volatil si el usuario borra datos de navegacion, deberias mejor almacenarlo en una BD para tener mas seguridad de los datos.

Sin embargo para lo que pide se me ocurre algo como lo siguiente

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check" id="box" onclick="clicked(this)">
<script>
function clicked(checkBox){        
    localStorage.setItem('state', checkBox.checked);
    checkBox.disabled = true;
}

function getState(){
    let state = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if(!state){
        return;
    }
    let checkBox = document.querySelector("#box");
    checkBox.checked = state;
    checkBox.disabled = true;

}

getState()
```

Este segmento de codigo consta de dos funciones, la primera recibe el evento `onClick` y obtiene la información del `checkbox` y la almacena en el `localstorage` ademas de desactivar tu `checkbox` esta funcion solo se ejecuta si el `checkbox` esta activado en caso contrario se omite, en la segunda funcion se recupera la variable del `localstorage` si existe entonces se sale de la funcion en caso contrario setea el valor y desactiva el `checkbox` espero que te funcione.

### Edicion

Para almacenar la informacion en una base de datos mysql con php desde una vista se puede hacer mas o menos de la siguiente manera, hay que considerar que se necesita jquery para esta acción ya que hace uso de ajax

```
function clicked(checkBox){        
    $.ajax({
       url: 'route/saveState.php',
       type: "POST",
       data: {state: checkBox.checked},       
       success: function (data) {  
           checkBox.disabled = true;
       },
       error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
}

function getState(){
    $.ajax({
       url: 'route/getState.php',
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {  
           let error = data.error;
           if(error){
              return;
           }
           let checkBox = document.querySelector("#box");
           checkBox.checked = data.state;
           checkBox.disabled = true;
       },
       error: function (data) { alert(data.responseText); }
}

getState()
```

Con eso se almacena y se consulta mediante ajax a un par de archivos de php nada mas haciendo el codigo correspondiente

Comment: lo pruebo y te notifico @ivan !!!! te diré que probé borrando caché (no cookies), apagando el PC y no se quitó la selección usando localStorage, eso hablando del primer código y sin usar el segundo y claro, omitiendo los detalles que buscó eliminar. Por cierto, cómo lo harías con Bd, ya que no se inserta ningún dato, bueno, creo

Comment: Depende de que estés usando, ¿Usas php? ¿Usas node?

Comment: php utilizo @ivan

Comment: Acabo de editar

Comment: de acuerdo @ivan!!! , hoy pruebo todo, solo una cosa, ¿los archivos php que llevan?, porque  nunca he guardado un state o vista, ahí si es mi primera vez 

Comment: Literal es una consulta simple donde debes recibir tu parametro por `POST`puedes basarte en [este](http://soyautodidacta.com/2013/03/insertar-datos-en-mysql-con-php-usando-ajax-para-evitar-recargar-la-pagina/)

Comment: ya he probado, tu primer propuesta funciona, solo que si se quita si borras cache, en el codigo que uso no sucede,si hay solucion seria grandioso, sino no importa :)

Comment: Como te comente anteriormente, la mejor manera seria con Ajax, para eso te puse el link en el comentario anterior

Comment: muy bien @ivan, probare con bd porque ya lei tu enlace y no me funciona, por cierto, a tu primera propuesta como puedo cambiarle el color al checkbox una vez desactivado, ahorita es gris

Comment: Lo que te pase es una guia para que puedas hacerlo similar, no igual, lo del color lo puedes ver [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_disabled.asp)